# Смена картинки в зависимости от date.getHours() js

Tags: javascript

Как сделать что бы картинка менялась по времени суток.
Вот мой кривой код, который заимствовал с разных сайтов.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  // текущая дата
  var date = new Date();


  var images = new Array();
  var j = date.getHours();
  var i = 0;

  images[0] = 'https://bestwomanday.ru/templates/FashionWomanv1/images/night.png';
  images[1] = 'https://bestwomanday.ru/templates/FashionWomanv1/images/morning.png';
  images[2] = 'https://bestwomanday.ru/templates/FashionWomanv1/images/afternoon.png';
  images[3] = 'https://bestwomanday.ru/templates/FashionWomanv1/images/evening.png';


  function viewImages() {
    document.getElementById("img_main").src = images[i];
    if (j >= 0 && j < 6) {
      i = 0;

    }
    //morning
    if (j >= 6 && j < 12) {
      i = 1;
    }
    //day
    if (j >= 12 && j < 18) {
      i = 2;


    }
    //evening
    if (j >= 18 && j < 0) {
      i = 3;


    }
    setTimeout("viewImages()", 5000);

  }
</script>

<img src="" id="img_main" style="width:1024px;margin:100000 0;position: relative;text-align: left;padding:0px 0px 0px no-repeat;height:220px;">

<script>
  viewImages();
</script>
```

Comment: Так а в чем проблема-то? что Вы хотите?

Comment: @cyadvert Проблема в том, что куски кода бездумно надерганы из сети. При этом понимания работы javascript у человека нет никакого.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Ниже приведен полный текст html файла. Код немного переработан и исправлены Ваши недочеты.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<img src="" id="img_main" style="width:1024px; height:220px;">

<script>
    var images = new Array();
    images[0] = 'https://bestwomanday.ru/templates/FashionWomanv1/images/night.png';
    images[1] = 'https://bestwomanday.ru/templates/FashionWomanv1/images/morning.png';
    images[2] = 'https://bestwomanday.ru/templates/FashionWomanv1/images/afternoon.png';
    images[3] = 'https://bestwomanday.ru/templates/FashionWomanv1/images/evening.png';

    function viewImages()
    {
        var date = new Date();
        var j = date.getHours();
        var i = 0;

        if (j >= 0 && j < 6) i = 0;
        if (j >= 6 && j < 12) i = 1;
        if (j >= 12 && j < 18) i = 2;
        if (j >= 18 && j < 0) i = 3;
        document.getElementById("img_main").src = images[i];
    }

    viewImages();
    setInterval("viewImages()", 1000);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: а почему не `i=math.ceil(j/6)` ?

Comment: @splash58 Потому что я исправлял его код, чтобы он работал (чтобы картинка менялась - такова задача). А не занимался оптимизацией, совершенствованием, написанием красивого кода и обучением других языку javascript.